# Splitting of certain short exact sequences in context of Clifford theory

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

I am reading section 7.B on Clifford theory in 
[this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04714) and hope someone can help me understand some of the arguments there.

Let me shortly explain the part of the setup which I need for my question:

$X$ is a normal subgroup of $Y$, $M$ is a $kX$-module ($k$ is a field) which is stable under $Y$ and we set $A = \text{End}_{kX}(M)$.
Suppose that the characteristic of $k$ does not divide the order of $Y/X$.

Under these conditions, it is stated that any short exact sequence 
$$1 \to 1 + J(A) \to Z \to Y/X \to 1$$
is split and the explanation  which is given is that $1 + J(A)$ is an extension of abelian groups since $1 + J(A)^i/ (1 + J(A)^{i + 1}) \cong J(A)^i/J(A)^{i+1}$ and these are $k(Y/X)$-modules.
I am missing some understanding to infer the splitting of the sequence from this explanation and would appreciate if someone could clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to consider your extension as a factor set $$f:Y/X\times Y/X\to 1+J(A)$$ and show that it must be equivalent to a trivial one. For this you first consider the image of $f$ in $(1+J(A))/(1+J(A)^2)\cong J(A)/J(A)^2$. 
The last group is abelian, so since $char(k)\nmid |Y/X|$ the resulting sequence $$1\to (1+J(A))/(1+J(A)^2)\to \tilde{Z}\to Y/X\to 1$$ splits. This means that you can choose $f$ above in such a way that the image of $f$ is contained in the subgroup $1+J(A)^2$. You finish by induction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to me I am missing some knowledge here concerning the connection between abelian groups, prime divisors and splitting sequences. I am sorry if this seems trivial to you, but could you explain to me in a bit more detail why the resulting sequence is split?

Comment: sure. The easiest way to see it is that when the kernel $R$ is abelian, then you get an action of $Y/X$ on $R$, and extensions correspond to elements in $H^2(Y/X,R)$. In the last abelian group, all elemenets have finite order dividing the order of $Y/X$. On the other hand, if $R$ is a vector space over $K$, then the same will be true for this abelian group. If $K$ has characteristic zero then this group must be zero. If $K$ has characteristic $p$ then this group will also have characteristic $p$, and if $p\nmid |Y/X|$ then the group is again zero.

Comment: All these things can be found in any standard book on cohomology of groups, for example the one of Brown.